# The paging of gridview not display the data correctly

Tags: asp.net

I have a calendar that when we click on a date, it will display the data retrieved from the database in a gridview. Since having a lot of data, I do paging for the gridview. But then, the paging not working fine since its not loaded data correctly.

What I have done and what it will display after I click paging
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1SpskVi4U5LTUJGBjjyvbWNKHD9PLb0az?usp=sharing

Comment: we need more details to understand your issue. can you show some code?

Comment: @SunilDhappadhule I have given the code link in my question

Comment: Already check your link. It is  not working

Comment: @SunilDhappadhule https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1SpskVi4U5LTUJGBjjyvbWNKHD9PLb0az

Comment: @SunilDhappadhule, are you able to view the content of the latest given link?